# Trying to fix the position of Buttons

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to change the places of the buttons from left to right at the top.

Here is the code below:

```
import wx 

class Example(wx.Frame): 

    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
      super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,300)) 

      self.InitUI() 
      self.Centre() 
      self.Show()

    def InitUI(self): 
      p = wx.Panel(self) 
      vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 


      for label in range(8):
         b2 = wx.Button(p, label =str(label)) 
         vbox.Add(b2,0,wx.VERTICAL) 
         hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 

      for label in range(8):
         b3 = wx.Button(p, label = "Btn3") 
         vbox.Add(b3,0,wx.RIGHT) 
         hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 

      p.SetSizer(vbox) 

app = wx.App() 
Example(None, title = 'BoxSizer demo') 
app.MainLoop()
```

The output is showing like this:

[image]

But I want the btn3 to the right side like this

1. 1 btn3
2. 2 btn3
3. 3 btn3
4. 4 btn3

Here (1,2,3,4) are buttons with btn3 (buttons).

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want the `btn3` buttons in a vertical line to the right of the other buttons.
There are various options, `GridSizer` and `FlexGridSizer` spring to mind but in your code you have already introduced a horizontal `BoxSizer` but not used it, so this code below will use that.
Load the vertical boxsizers and then load those into the horizontal sizer.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
      super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,300))

      self.InitUI()
      self.Centre()
      self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
      p = wx.Panel(self)
      vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
      vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
      hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

      for label in range(8):
         b2 = wx.Button(p, label =str(label))
         vbox1.Add(b2,0,0)

      for label in range(8):
         b3 = wx.Button(p, label = "Btn3")
         vbox2.Add(b3,0,0)

      hbox.Add(vbox1)
      hbox.Add(vbox2)

      p.SetSizer(hbox)

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title = 'BoxSizer demo')
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]